# Action_caching not working when using thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, thin

I have an application running on my development machine using Aptana & Webrick.

If I turn on caching (action_caching, written to tmp/cache), it works fine, but when I deploy the application to the testserver (running thin instead of webrick) the caching does not work...i.e. there are no files written to tmp/cache.

as far as I can tell, the webserver is the only difference here (even running the development-environment on the test server.

any clues?

Comment: The user/group does not have permissions. What are the user permissions on that directory?

Comment: Good point - It's run as a windows service. But even if i run it from the console as local admin, or with my user, there's still nothing written to the tmp/cache folder.. (which exists and files are written to it if I run it locally)... bummer

Comment: but wait :) there seems to be something wrong with the user permissions - i'll have to check back with our IT to see whats wrong, so I'll close this one until further notice.. thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem: I was running thin as a windows service, which didn't shut down or restart properly when trying to do so in "Services".
Unfortunately without notice. Therefore no changes took effect..

So after restarting the server, the caching-problem dissappeared. running thin now from the command line...